# Asynchronous update using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My model contains a *large* data object that I update from code-behind (currently this happens on the UI thread but I intend to do this in a worker later on). One of my windows has a viewmodel for this model and outputs this data object using an `IValueConverter`. The problem is that this conversion takes several seconds. Hence, I need my window to fetch this updated data asynchronously. How can this be done?

**MyControl.xaml:**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:DataViewModel x:Name="dataViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

**Then in code:**

```
// This triggers my value converter and blocks the UI for several seconds!
dataViewModel.HeavyObject = data;
```

Where should the multi-threading code go? Should it be part of the viewmodel or my value converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at `IsAsync="True"` for your binding and also check `PriorityBinding`.

[here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-priority-bindings) you find more about PriorityBinding

Comment: Does this handle the case where the object is being updated twice in a row? I.e. the lengthy operation A starts, a new update triggers a new lengthy operation B, A finishes, B finishes. In this case A is not of interest!

Comment: I tried `IsAsync=True` and my converter seems to get a disposed value: [System.ObjectDisposedException] = {"Cannot access a disposed object."} ??

Comment: Can you tell us which object was disposed?

Comment: The value sent to the IValueConverter. I googled this and it seems converters should not perform lengthy operations. Instead, the conversion should take place in a worker thread issued by the viewmodel. Does this approach sound familiar? (Other than this, your hint of `IsAsync` suffices as answer.)

Comment: doin it at viewmodel is always better :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a choice between your view-model and value converter, I'd vote for the view-model.  However, I'd much rather see your long-running operations in a repository or client-side service that are responsible for interacting with your data store.

Comment: Client-side service? Is this a common pattern? Do you know of some good tutorials on this?

Comment: It's common on a lot of the projects I work on :).  It puts the responsibility of data interaction into a dedicated local "service".  This service can be used by the entire app or it can be more granular: say, one per view-model.  If you're familar with MVC, it's a lot like a repository.  I don't know of any tutorials, but Dino Esposito uses this, so maybe a search will yield some good results.